# Perform function after notify in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, listen

If a notification is sent in postgresql, how can I trigger a function by using listen? I know it can be done in another programming language, and I know you can send triggers after changes to tables, but how do I only trigger a function after a notification inside postgresql? Something like:

```
LISTEN <channel> THEN PERFORM ...
```

Comment: I don't think you can. The LISTEN is a client-connection thing, not something that sits running inside postgresql continually. Why not just call the function when you NOTIFY?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I see. An advantage with notify is that it's asynchronous and there is no dependence. If the function is called after a trigger and it fails, the entire transaction will fail.

Comment: It sound like what you want is an "independent transaction" or "autonomous transaction" which PostgreSQL doesn't support (as of v15). If you want asynchronous actions without writing "C" (which you would need for a background worker) then you'll need a separate connection that is capable of reconnecting etc.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Yes, I guess it's easiest to have an external script.